# Why "if statement" doesn't work at seeds.rb on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm creating a Rails 6.0.2.2 App.

My problem is that `if` statement in `seeds.rb` file not works.

Just for curiosity, I added the if statement below.

```
if Plan.count == 0 # always true -- though it already have a lot of plan data.
  Plan.create!(name: 'スタート')
  Plan.create!(name: 'ライト')
  Plan.create!(name: 'スタンダード')
end
```

However, every time I execute `rake db:seed`, it **always seeds** those data.

When I run `rails console`, it returns something like...

```
irb(main):073:0> Plan.count
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "plans"
=> 3
irb(main):074:0> Plan.count
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "plans"
=> 6
irb(main):076:0> Plan.count
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "plans"
=> 9
irb(main):077:0> Plan.count
   (1.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "plans"
=> 12
```

Why `Plan.all.count` returns `0` wrongly?

Comment: Can you try Plan.all.count instead of Plan.count. Also it would be useful if you could add the code `p Plan.all` at the start of the seed.rb file so we can narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. Create an array of plant names, iterate and create like below

```rb
["Plant 1", "Plant 2", "Plant 3"].each do |plant|
  Plant.find_or_create_by!(name: plant)
end
```

Comment: Mobile Typo. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Be careful typing in code that you can't run and prove. It's a good way to get your response voted down quickly if it won't run. I always run mine prior to pasting it, and almost always show its output; It's a quality check I do for myself.